# Clean and Build Java EE Project when modified

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am working on a Java EE and Spring project.

Everytime I modify my code except in JSP, I have to clean and build my project and restart Tomcat.

What should I do so that when I modify my code in Java, XML or Properties i don't have to clean and build my project?

Comment: You can buy [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) or the word you should search for is _hotswap_. But this will solve only changes in java code. If you make changes in properties, xml you need to restart the server.

Comment: I don't have problem in restarting the server. What really bothers me is cleaning and building the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the option of Build Automatically under Project tab in eclipse. By doing that the project will get build automatically whenever any change is made in your project code , as well as after project build it will form a new war/ear and deploys in tomcat. Without doing this manually everytime.